# Передать string в функцию, когда требуется char

Tags: c++, массивы, строки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поступить в моей проблеме. Есть функция (библиотеки нестандартной), который в качестве аргумента требуется **const char ***. Но у меня нет массива char, есть лишь переменная типа string. Можно ли как-то передать в функцию именно string, а не const char?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Передавайте `.c_str()` - это и есть `const char*`-представление строки.

```
string s;

...

void f(const char* c){ ... };

...

f(s.c_str());
```

Comment: Простите, а возможно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы функция сама возвращала требующееся значение?

Например, если требутся string, то стояло бы return str. Если требуется cont char*, то возвращала бы str.c_str().

Comment: Сделайте перегрузку функции с нужными аргументами и возвращаемыми значениями

Comment: Не понял ваш вопрос. Есть функция, которая возвращает string - со своим кодом, другая, которая возвращает char* - со своим... Что в этом случае означает "сама бы возвращала"? Она возвращает то, что указываете ей вы...

Comment: Функция не имеет никаких параметров (поэтому и различий в параметрах быть не может). Отсюда следует, что писать две реализации одной и той же функции, отличающиеся только возвращаемыми значениями, также невозможно (появляется ошибка о невозможности перегрузки функции). Вот у меня и возникает вопрос, а можно ли как-то сделать, чтобы при затребовании const char * возвращала функция str.c_str(), в противном случае - просто str.

Comment: А, я туплю. Можно же написать прототип функции, которой требуется const char * и туда уже передавать string, и там уже преобразовывать. Извините)) Спасибо больше всем